# Test case for destructuring in clojure for database connectivity

Tags: clojure, testcase

I started working on clojure a week back and i am not able to write a test case for the below code for destructuring of maps using default values:

```
(defn connect-db [{:keys [host port db-name username password]
                   :or   {host     "localhost"
                          port     12345
                          db-name  "my-db"
                          username "db-user"
                          password "secret"}
                   :as cfg}]
  (if (= " " host) 
    "Error: host name not available"
    (try
      (println "connecting to:" host "port:" port "db-name:" db-name
               "username:" username "password:" password)
      (catch Exception e(str "caught exception:" (.getMessage e))))))
```

The test case should be written using deftest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is much to gain from testing destructuring, because it's a core part of the language and is built into `fn`, `defn`, `let` etc. Assume that it works and test only your own code. If you want to build confidence that it works the way you expect, play about with it in the REPL.  There are plenty of examples [here](http://clojure.org/guides/destructuring).

We can try out some defaults like this:

```
(let [{:keys [a b] 
       :or {a "a" b "b"}} 
      nil]
 [a b])

=> ["a" "b"]
```

Comment: Yes, it is of not much use but i have solved this by following the above sample code.

Answer (score 0):

```
(deftest con-db
 (is (= true (map? db)))
 (is (= true (function? connectdb)))
 (connectdb ["01" "20" "02" "03" "04"] {:host "localhost" :port 8888 :db-name "dbname" :username "name" :password "admin"})
 (is(.equals "connecting: remote port: 8888 db-name: dbname username: name password: admin" outputdb))
 (is(not(.equals "string" outputdb)))
 (is(.equals "01-20" output))
  (is(= 400 (- y x)))))
```